# Display cell section wise crashes iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have `Tableview` with sections in it from `A` to `Z` (no of sections are not fixed i calculated dynamically)

I want to display like this:
[image]:
My array values: **msg_array=["AajKaCatch","AajKaItem","Anari","Big C Mobiles","Big Flix","BigRock","caksonflowers, ...."]**

when i try to display like this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it shows `NSInvalidArgumentException`

`cell.textLabel.text=[[[msg_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Merchant_Name"];`

***please help and Thanks In advance.***

Comment: msg_array contains only string objects. It should contains objects of NSArray which will contains NSDictionary type objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is like:

```
array{object,object,object,object,object};
```

In such a situation, you can't use like:

```
[[msg_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

Because for implementing such one, the `[msg_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]` should return an array.

So implementing this, you need to try like this:

```
array{array{objects starts with 'A'},array{objects starts with 'B'},array{objects starts with 'C'}};
```

Comment: `-(void)createAlphabetArray{
    NSMutableArray *tempFirstLetterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < [msg_array count]; i++) {
        NSMutableArray *temp=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSString *letterString = [[[msg_array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Merchant_Name"] substringToIndex:1];
        if (![tempFirstLetterArray containsObject:[letterString uppercaseString]]) {
            [tempFirstLetterArray addObject:letterString];
            
            [temp addObject:[[msg_array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Merchant_Name"]];
        }
    }
}`

Comment: You are right dude, but how to add elements in my array ? above is my code i wrote but adds only first element of character

Comment: @Krunal: in your code the if block will be true when it find a new character, in all other cases it'll be false. so it won't add other objects

Comment: then, How should i add it ?

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing this:

```
[[[msg_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Merchant_Name"];
```

You are accessing an element of msg_array as if it was a NSArray, that contains a `NSDictionary`.

But, inside of msg_array you just have `NSStrings`.

The structure you are triying to access is:

```
NSArray -> NSArray -> NSDictionary
```

And you have

```
NSArray -> NSString
```

Comment: You are right dude, but how to add elements in my array ? below is my code i wrote but it adds only first element of character

Comment: `-(void)createAlphabetArray{ NSMutableArray *tempFirstLetterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; for (int i = 0; i < [msg_array count]; i++) { NSMutableArray *temp=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; NSString *letterString = [[[msg_array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Merchant_Name"] substringToIndex:1]; if (![tempFirstLetterArray containsObject:[letterString uppercaseString]]) { [tempFirstLetterArray addObject:letterString]; [temp addObject:[[msg_array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Merchant_Name"]]; } } }`

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing for contact info and other things like that using FKRSearchBarTableViewController, see the link and below is mine code for [FKRSearchBarTableViewController](https://github.com/fabiankr/TableViewSearchBar/blob/master/TableViewSearchBar/FKRSearchBarTableViewController.m)

```
    - (id)initWithSectionIndexes:(BOOL)showSectionIndexes withDataSource:(NSArray*) dataSource withControllerId:(int) ControllerId forGroup:(int)groupId
{
if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil])) {
    self.title = @"Search Bar";
    NSLog(@"%d",groupId);
    _groupID = groupId;
    _controllerId = ControllerId;

    _showSectionIndexes = showSectionIndexes;

    _famousPersons = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:dataSource];
    if (showSectionIndexes) {
        UILocalizedIndexedCollation *collation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];

        NSMutableArray *unsortedSections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[[collation sectionTitles] count]];
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [[collation sectionTitles] count]; i++) {
            [unsortedSections addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
        }
        if(ControllerId == 5)
        {
        for (Person *personName in self.famousPersons) {

               // NSInteger index = [collation sectionForObject:[personName objectForKey:@"FirstName"] collationStringSelector:@selector(description)];
            NSLog(@"%@",personName.firstName);
            NSInteger index = [collation sectionForObject:personName.firstName collationStringSelector:@selector(description)];
                [[unsortedSections objectAtIndex:index] addObject:personName];
        }
        }
        else
        {
            for (NSDictionary *personName in self.famousPersons) {

                 NSInteger index = [collation sectionForObject:[personName objectForKey:@"FirstName"] collationStringSelector:@selector(description)];

                [[unsortedSections objectAtIndex:index] addObject:personName];
            }

        }

        NSMutableArray *sortedSections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:unsortedSections.count];
        for (NSMutableArray *section in unsortedSections) {
            [sortedSections addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[collation sortedArrayFromArray:section collationStringSelector:@selector(description)]]];
        }

        self.sections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:sortedSections];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to make the list more dynamic, solution should be

```
// given NSArray names = your full list of name
//       NSArray indexes = your list of index

NSMutableArray *nameSections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:26];
NSMutableArray *filteredIndexes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:26];

for (NSString *index in indexes) {

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"SELF beginswith[c] %@",index];
    NSArray *filterNames = [names filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    if(filterNames.count>0){
        [nameSections addObject:filterNames];
        [filteredIndexes addObject:index];
    }
}


NSLog(@"filteredIndexes %@",filteredIndexes);
NSLog(@"nameSections %@",nameSections);


numOfSection = nameSections.count
numOfRow = [[numOfSection indexOfObject:section]count];
name = [[numOfSection indexOfObject:section]] indexOfObject:row];


// print log
//given indexes array a~z

names (
"a_string",
"a_string2",
"b_string",
"b_string2"
)

filteredIndexes (
a,
b
)

nameSections (
    (
    "a_string",
    "a_string2"
    ),
    (
    "b_string",
    "b_string2"
    )
)
```